# Using two Buttons on one Activity

Tags: button, if-statement, android-activity

I'm still new to android. I have a kids book that l have done with two buttons "READ TO ME" and "READ TO MYSELF".

Read to me onclick will play a recording as it reads the book but it goes to SoundOne Activity.
Read to myself will display text and it leads to PageOne Activity.

How do l create some sort of an "if statement" such that when l click read to me it will play the recording but lead to PageOne Activity. And when l click read to myself it will display the text but still leads to PageOne Activity

This might help reduce the number of classes l have created so far and avoid ANR l assume. Some source code or a tutorial will help Thanks in advance my code is below:

```
package com.inerds.donkiejoukie;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.content.Context;

public class Fbone extends MainActivity {
    MediaPlayer one;
    MediaPlayer mb;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fbone);
        one = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pageone);
        mb = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menubar);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pageflip);
        ImageButton imageButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        imageButton1.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View vone) {
                mb.pause();
                mb.stop();
                mp.start();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PageOne.class));
                finish();
            }

        });
        ImageButton readtome = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.readtome);
        readtome.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mb.pause();
                mb.stop();
                one.start();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SoundOne.class));
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Intent` mechanism is used to communicate from one `Activity` to another. In the `Intent`, as well as a class to start, you can specify the name of an action to perform, as well as other options. In this case, you might want to use an *extra* to tell the following class whether to play sound or not. When you start the intent:

```
Intent nextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SoundOne.class);
// Put true or false in the next line according to which click handler you're in.
nextActivity.putBooleanExtra(SoundOne.extra_enableSound, true);
startActivity(nextActivity);
```

and then in your `SoundOne` activity, you need a constant field for the extra name:

```
static final String extra_enableSound = "enableSound";
```

and you can find the value of this extra from your `onCreate`, or wherever you want to start the sound:

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(extra_enableSound, false)) {
    // start the sound
}
```

Now your `PageOne` activity is unused and can be deleted. The [documentation for `Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) tells you what other information you can stash in there.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, click the green check mark on the left to mark it as correct. That's the Stack Overflow way of saying thanks, and it lets other visitors know the problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a professional programmer so this might not be the best way to do this, but it works well for me with minimal code.

Here's what I'm doing.

Set an "onClick" for the buttons in my XML

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="144dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
    android:onClick="sendMessage1"
    android:text="@string/cancel"
     />
```

the in the activity i set up my buttons

```
    Button button1;
Button button2;
```

then use a sendmessage instead of onButtonclick

```
public void sendMessage(View view) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void sendMessage1(View view) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
package com.inerds.donkiejoukie;    

public class Fbone extends MainActivity {

MediaPlayer one;
MediaPlayer mb;
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fbone);
        one = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pageone);
    mb = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menubar);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pageflip);
    ImageButton imageButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);     
    ImageButton readtome = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.readtome);
    imageButton1.setOnClickListener (handleOnClickListener);
    readtome.setOnClickListener (handleOnClickListener);

}

private OnClickListener handleOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

     switch(v.getId()){

  case R.id.imageButton1: 
   mb.pause();
        mb.stop();
        mp.start();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PageOne.class));
        finish();
       break;

  case R.id.readtome:
        mb.pause();
        mb.stop();
        one.start();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SoundOne.class));
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
         audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100, 0);
         finish();
       break;
  }
}
};
}
```

Comment: What kinda answer is this ?